# Add a Reference from a C# App to a DLL compiled without /clr?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, pinvoke

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to build a Solution with two Projects: a C# Console App and a C++ DLL. I want the app to call a function from the dll using P/Invoke. Therefore I'm trying to add the dll as a Reference to the C# app. But when I try the Add Reference command, Visual Studio won't let me do it unless I set the /clr property on the dll (under Configuration Properties:General). Now, I thought that P/Invoke could handle plain-old win32 dlls. Indeed, if I build my dll without /clr and just copy it by hand to bin/Debug, then the app runs fine. So why is /clr required to add the dll as a reference? And if VS won't let me add it, is there some (clean) workaround so that my app finds the dll?

I see that someone had a similar issue here (though with a 3rd-party dll):
[Unable to add a DLL Reference to VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377019/unable-to-add-a-dll-reference-to-vs-2008) The answer he got was to build a wrapper. But this isn't really necessary, since the app can use the dll just fine; it's just the Add Reference step that doesn't work. And besides, won't the wrapper code need a reference to the dll, raising the same problem as before? I'd really like an answer that doesn't involve writing a wrapper at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just add a post-build step to copy your unmanaged DLL to your project directory?  You don't need a "reference" to be able to refer to an unmanaged DLL, and it sounds like the only problem you're experiencing is due to the file not being automatically copied into the search path.

Comment: I wrote a pre-build step for the C# app using this command line: copy "$(SolutionDir)Debug\MathDll.dll" "$(TargetDir)". Alas, I wish the "Add Reference" functionality worked, because now I've got to maintain this, and I guess it will be different for release builds.... I don't really see why "Add Reference" shouldn't handle this sort of thing.

Comment: I just found a slightly cleaner way of doing this. Rather than using a pre/post-build DOS command, I added the dll to the C# project as an "Existing Item." Then under its properties, I set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer." (Its "Build Action" is "Content.") This still seems a little hackish to me, but at least it fixes the Debug-vs-Release issue, and it's a little easier to spot.

Comment: Oops--I realized my second workaround does not resolve the Debug-vs-Release issue, because I referenced the dll from the Debug folder. On the other hand, the first workaround could handle this issue by changing the command to copy "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\MathDll.dll" "$(TargetDir)".

Comment: @Paul I used copy "$(ProjectDir)Resources\*" "$(TargetDir)" since I put the DLLs in my resources directory. Where is the list of "$ ..." that VS recognizes?

Comment: be careful to check **errorlevel** after _each_ batch command in post build step because MSBuild ignores error code for all commands except the last one [(read more)](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

When using PInvoke on a C++ DLL, it is not necessary to add a reference.  References are only needed when you are calling managed code in another DLL.  Simply put the C++ DLL in the same directory and add it's name to the `DllImport` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could add the C++-DLL as a linked resource to your C#-DLL. This would make .NET copy your C++-DLL wherever it copies the C#-DLL even into the GAC.
Theoretically means that there are some disadvantages:

- You could instruct the C# compiler (csc.exe) via command line options to add the linked resource but I never found a way to do it via .csproj file or even Visual Studio
- If the C#-DLL contains WinForms user controls and you want to use it in the designer it wont work because the Winforms-Designer copies the C#-DLL to a temporary location where it loads it but it ignores the linked resource.
- I don't know if it works if you put your C#-DLL into the GAC (yes the C++-DLL would also go into as a resource, but I don't know if it is found when running your C#-DLL!)

So if none of the above is a no-go for you you can call csc.exe the following:

```
csc.exe ... /linkresource:cpp.dll
```

Hope this may help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved a similar issue by doing the following:

1. On all **development machines**, added the path to dll-s in question to PATH enviromental variable. That way all the developers could debug all the executables that have a reference to the assembly with unmanaged dll-s, without the need to write a post build script for every executable.
2. For production, nightly msbuild task builds everything to a single folder, and the unmanaged dll-s that are marked as "Content/Always copy" are automatically included with the build of that one assembly that they are a part of.