# Is there a way to reference a c++ project from a c# project in the same solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++

In my solution we have projects both in c#, that controls some GUI and networking work, and c++, that manages some hardware interactions. In my c# project I have the proper PInvokes and am able to use the c++ output dll with no issue but in order to do it, I have to manually copy the output dll to the build directory or create a build script that manages the copy.

My issue with this method is that the solution, in reality, has many many projects, something like 150 at the moment, covering c++, c, c#, and vb.net. We create and delete projects all the time and managing the copy scripts is becoming a major pain. Especially since not all of the projects rely on each other and we have like 20 different build configurations.

Is it possible to simply have the c# project reference the c++ project and automatically copy the project output the same way it does with other managed projects without using post build scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the way I do it and have always done it is by obviously using Visual Studio, and assuming this C++ projects are VS projects you can easily create a VS Solution containing multiple projects that you can organize with "Solution Folders". The organization of your projects inside the solution is really up to how you want to organize it. It resembles a file system with nested folders. Needless to say that you can host projects in different languages such as C++, C#, VB...I'm not too sure if you can include a C project or not, that's out of my expertise.

See a screenshot below of a solution I created to demonstrate this...

[image]

[image]

Notice that "Business" has a nested  solution folder (Utils) which contains a C++ project (ERM.CPPLibraries) and a VB project (ERM.VBLibraries). Then if you reference projects within the solution (Right click -> Add Reference), you will not need to copy the output assemblies everytime you compile your solution (or project(s)) VS is smart enough to resolve all dependencies, resolve them and update them.

Hope it gives you an idea

#### Edit based on comment

In simple words...No, it's not possible to reference a unmanaged project from a managed project in a VS solution. You can reference DLLs but not projects itself

Comment: This doesn't quite solve it. The problem is that I cannot reference a native project from a managed project... Even if they are int eh same solution.

Comment: Ok, since you tagged VS in your question I was assuming it was all managed code. If that is the case then a little bit more involved as stated here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107694/how-do-i-add-a-reference-to-an-unmanaged-c-project-called-by-a-c-sharp-project